# How Can I Create a Dashed Line SKShapeNode from a UIBezierPath, Using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

All of the explanations I've found seem to say the same thing.  I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```
var linePath = UIBezierPath()
linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))

var pattern : [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]
linePath.setLineDash(pattern, count: pattern.count, phase: 0)
linePath.lineWidth = 10
linePath.lineCapStyle = .round

let shape = SKShapeNode()
shape.path = linePath.cgPath
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white

self.addChild(shape)
```

This code successfully draws a line but `shape` does not inherit the dashed properties of `linePath`, including even the width.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let linePath = UIBezierPath()
linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))

var pattern: [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]
let dashed = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath (linePath.CGPath, nil, 0, pattern, 2)

var shape = SKShapeNode(path: dashed)
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white

self.addChild(shape)
```

NOTE: In Swift 3 `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath` has been replaced by `path.copy(dashingWithPhase:lengths:)`

e.g.

`let dashed = SKShapeNode(path: linePath.cgPath.copy(dashingWithPhase: 2, lengths: pattern))`